# How to align boxes one below the other with checkbox and add fixed label inside boxes?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm building a website and have an issue while creating some boxes.

I have a checkbox which, when checked, opens two new fields where users can input a value.

I would like to have the fields aligned with the checkbox one below the other and also have the label "Price" and "Profit" inside the box field on the left.

The labels never disappear.

I tried different things but couldn't make it work. Basically what you can see on the 2nd screenshot is what I want.

How can I solve this?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import useStore from "./store";
import "./TakeProfit.css";

const TakeProfit = () => {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
  const [price, setPrice] = useState(0);
  const [percent, setPercent] = useState(0);
  const asset = useStore((state) => state.asset); // get the asset from the store
  const marketPrice = 100; // Replace this with the actual market price from API
  const setTakeProfit = useStore((state) => state.setTakeProfit);

  useEffect(() => {
    let finalTakeProfit;
    if (percent !== 0) {
      finalTakeProfit = marketPrice * (1 + percent / 100);
    } else {
      finalTakeProfit = price;
    }
    setTakeProfit(finalTakeProfit);
  }, [checked, price, percent, setTakeProfit, marketPrice]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // reset the form when the asset changes
    setChecked(false);
    setPrice(0);
    setPercent(0);
  }, [asset]); // listen for changes in the asset

  return (
    <div className="container-tp">
      <label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={checked}
          onChange={() => setChecked(!checked)}
        />
        Take-Profit
      </label>
      {checked && (
        <div className="input-row-tp">
          <label>
            PRICE
            <input
              type="number"
              onChange={(e) => setPrice(parseFloat(e.target.value))}
            />
          </label>
          <label>
            PROFIT%
            <input
              type="number"
              onChange={(e) => setPercent(parseFloat(e.target.value))}
            />
          </label>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default TakeProfit;


.container-tp {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.input-row-tp {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}
```

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: This is, at its core, an HTML/CSS question. Please provide rendered HTML and the relevant CSS in a demo snippet using the editor.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.input-row-tp {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  /* added codes*/
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

Here is the modified markup and CSS for that output if it helps:

```css
.container-tp {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  background: #222322;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 20px;
}

.input-row-tp {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;      
  width: 50%;

  ::placeholder { /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */        
    color: #ffffff;
    opacity: 1; /* Firefox */
  }
}

.input-row-tp input{
  background: #272827;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #494a49;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-tp">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox"/>
    Take-Profit
  </label>

  <div class="input-row-tp">
    <input type="number" placeholder="PRICE"/>

    <input type="number" placeholder="PROFIT%"/>
  </div>
</div>
```